# Language fallback stack

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have 4 language versions on my website.
Is there a way to define a language fallback order?

For example, if I'm on a node page and the language is set to English and there's no English translation I'd like Drupal to look for French, then German, then Spanish translation.

Comment: Interested in this as well.

Comment: Are you talking about translating the interface (locale) or the content?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: For the interface you have this module https://drupal.org/project/language_fallback

Answer (score 1):

If you have language fallback enabled, then the fallback order is the order of the languages you have set at `admin/config/regional/language`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Language Hierarchy](https://www.drupal.org/project/language_hierarchy) module.
It works with entity translation, i18n menu, i18n node translation and string translations.